# How to use 'set interval' Function in codeigniter for automatic database backup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, backup, setinterval

I want to take backup of my database in each hours. Am already use the default backup function of **codeigniter** . How can I call that function automatically in each hour using **setinterval function** or any other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have server then call your php file through cron jobs. 
If you want to do this on you local machine then you have to use task schedule of operating system. and open your backup function url in browser